# $scope is undefined in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the worlds simplest controller which i want access to $scope but it is "undefined" and I cannot, for the life of me work out why, however all the functions are called corectly, the DataService, etc is working perfectly, just i have no access to $scope?!

controller code is below

```
app = angular.module("windscreens", []);

app.controller('DamageCtrl', function($scope, DataService) {
  $scope.setDamageLocation = function(location) {
    DataService.getDamage().setLocation(location);
  };
  $scope.isLocation = function(requiredLocation) {
    return DataService.getDamage().getLocation() === requiredLocation;
  };
  $scope.progress = function() {
  };
});
```

Comment: How can you claim `DataService` is working when `$scope` is undefined? Where in your code does the error occur?

Comment: There isn't an error yet, I am trying to figure out how to get the function "progress" working, and went to look at what "$scope" was and got undefined - data service is working as on the front end, what triggers setLocation, and consumes isLocation is working 100% as expected

Comment: How did you *"look"* at `$scope`. I think your problem lies there.

Comment: break point in the setLocation function, then using console just doing "$scope"

Comment: The console is just the console. It will not enter the scope your script is in. You can check what value `$scope` references to by setting a breakpoint and look at the debug information the browser provides. I use Google Chrome for debugging and it will display the info in a panel to the right with all variables neatly categorized by scope.

Comment: thats what I did though.....? im managed to get it working by using the alternative way

Answer (score 0):

To access a property on the scope from your HTML template you only need to use the property name, you don't need to write $scope with it.

Example:

```
<button ng-click="progress()"></button>
```

In your javascript you will only have access to the $scope inside the controller and its functions. If you call an external resource, for example: DataService module, it won't have access to the $scope unless you pass it as an argument explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using the alternative syntax. As detailed below, still not sure why it wasn't working but hey hum

```
app.controller('DamageCtrl', ['$scope', 'DataService',
  function($scope, DataService) {
    $scope.setDamageLocation = function(location) {
      DataService.getDamage().setLocation(location);
    };

    $scope.isLocation = function(requiredLocation) {
      return DataService.getDamage().getLocation() === requiredLocation;
    };

    $scope.progress = function() {
      console.log($scope);
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: This approach is to protect injected arguments from code compressors. Was you code compressed by any means?

Comment: No, we are still in the dev phase, we don't minify until we are in testing - I dont know why it wasn't working, but it is now, and actually this way is arguablly better as you say as allows full minification!